# Laravel undefined variable in view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm new to laravel. Using version 5.3 and tried to search but don't see what I'm doing wrong. I keep getting an "Undefined variable: user" in my view. I'm also doing form model binding. Model binding works properly when manually entering URL. Just can't click on link to bring up edit view.

My routes:

```
Route::get('/profile/edit/{id}', 'ProfileController@getEdit');
Route::post('/profile/edit/{id}', 'ProfileController@postEdit');
```

My controller:

```
public function getEdit($id){

    $user= User::findOrFail($id);
    return view('profile.edit', compact('user'));
}
```

My view:

```
<li><a href="{{ url('/profile/edit', $user->id ) }}">Update profile</a></li>
```

My form:

```
{!! Form::model($user,['method' => 'POST', 'action'=>        ['ProfileController@postEdit', $user->id]]) !!}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function getEdit($id){

    $user= User::findOrFail($id);
    return view('profile.edit', ['user' => $user]);
}

public function postEdit($id){

    $user= User::findOrFail($id);
    return view('profile.edit', ['user' => $user]);
}
```

Comment: Tried that but still getting the same issue.

Comment: can you confirm you are actually using the getEdit method to render your view, and not the postEdit method?

Comment: Yes in my routes it's calling the getEdit. Is there another way to confirm it but I'm pretty sure.

Comment: add dd('confirm') to the first line of your getEdit method, or include the laravel debugbar package (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) and look under the routes tab. My hunch is that you're possibly making the user variable available to the wrong template.

Comment: Yes I did a dd and it is calling that method. I had to remove the variables from the route and method to get it to work with an error though.

Comment: Could the issue be because i;m passing he variable to my profile.edit and not my navigation where the it says the error is at? My profie.edit extends the navigation layout.

Comment: yes, the variable wont be made available to the parent template unless your specifically tell it to be like: @extends('master', ['user' => $user])

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the statement in your view

```
<li><a href="{{ url('/profile/edit', $user->id ) }}">Update profile</a></li>
```

is causing the issue. You may confirm this by looking at the URL in the address bar after clicking on the **Update profile** link.

Try changing it to this

```
<li><a href="{{ action('ProfileController@getEdit', $user->id ) }}">Update profile</a></li>
```

Comment: I changed it but I'm still getting undefined variable:user. After clicking, I see "myapp.dev/profile/edit" but the variable is not showing.

Comment: That's the problem then! You are seeing `myapp.dev/profile/edit` as the URL; but it should actually be `myapp.dev/profile/edit/1` (assuming `1` as user id).

Comment: Correct. I realize that's the problem from the beginning. I'm passing the variable as you can see from my controller and view but it's not showing in the URL

Answer (score 0):

Try this for pass data array in view

```
public function getEdit($id){
    $data['user'] = User::findOrFail($id);
    return view('profile.edit')->withdata($data);
}
```

in view page try to print $data

```
{{ print_r($data) }}
```

Comment: Tried that and got an error message...Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'name'

Comment: in model define table name and primaryKey.

Comment: yes in User model define table name and primary key

Comment: OK. I have added this to the model....protected $table = 'User' and
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

Comment: after that print_r($data) in controller after this line $data['user'] = User::findOrFail($id);

Comment: Ok so I still get the error user undefined when i click on the edit link but if I manually populate the URL with myapp.dev/profile/edit/1 it prints the users information in an array

Comment: Could the issue be because i;m passing he variable to my profile.edit and not my navigation where the it says the error is at? My profie.edit extends the navigation layout.

Comment: Could the issue be because i;m passing he variable to my profile.edit and not my navigation where the it says the error is at? My profie.edit extends the navigation layout.

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your getEdit method

```
public function getEdit($id){
    $user= User::findOrFail($id);
    dd($user);
    return view('profile.edit', compact('user'));
}
```

check if there is any data user variable.

Comment: Yes there is some data being displayed to the view in an array.

Comment: I think that you are displaying the below link at some other page.

My view:
<li><a href="{{ url('/profile/edit', $user->id ) }}">Update profile</a></li>
Can you please check $user is passed to that view.